# Leaflet.js How Do I only draw visible layers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I'm using leaflet.js to track a ton of assets. How can I only render the assets (layers) that are in the visible area (bounds)?

Comment: How many is "a ton"? How are they distributed geographically? Are they points, lines, polygons or topologies? Why do you want/feel the need to prune their rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting no help here, I begged for help on IRC. Leaflet does this automatically. Leaflet prunes vector layers, mostly. It also only renders vector features when the viewport changes, or when zoom levels change